# Getting Nothing from URL Parameters using $_GET

Tags: php, get, key-value

I've got this url: /admin.php?op=admin&action=delete&link=/showitems.php?id=8745

I need to get the op parameter and the action and the link parameters as well. If I code something like this:

```
$op = $_GET['op'];
echo $op; //the output is admin

$action = $_GET['action'];
echo $action; //The output is nothing; 

$link = $_GET['link'];
echo $link; //The output is nothing;

//IF I want to sanitize the data same happens with

$op = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"op",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
echo $op; //the output is admin
$action = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"action",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
echo $action; //the output is nothing
$link = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"link",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
echo $link; //the output is nothing

//If I go for the whole array of parameters there they are.
foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
    echo $key . " : " . $value; //The output is op : admin;action : deleteamp;link : /showitems.php?id=8745
}
```

what could it be the problem when I try to directly get the second or the third parameter like in this case action and link? Thanks for any advise. Greetings.

Comment: your comment is shure an answer ?

Comment: @Samuel Ahh quick wit and repartee, good recovery

Comment: I've changed it to just a string without the equal sign like: link=showitems and the the code behaves the same :( No echo for action or link, but in a foreach all of them are there.

Comment: @Diego : Please show us **how** and **where** this URL is build together.

Comment: admin.php gets the op key and then include PHP functions to handle CRUD operations as in Create and delete, so I need these parameters to perform those actions. Dynamicly I create links from my database and then I just added the href with jquey like: 

    $delete_btn.setAttribute('href','/admin.php?op=admin&amp;action=delete&amp;link=shownoters');

Thanks for your time.

Comment: if you got an output from `foreach()` like  `op : admin;` instead of `op : admin` without semicolon `;` or `action : deleteamp;` instead of `action : delete` without `amp;` . There is something wrong with the request string.